# Is there a way to use solr text tagger along with n-edge-gram filter

Tags: filter, solr

I am making a solr autosuggest feature. Basically I intended to suggest all possible tag combinations from a text string. 
Let's take an example of search string:
**find all the route between Mars and Jupiter** .

Let assume there are multiple solr document starting with the text ***mars*** and ***jupiter***, like **mars1**, **mars2**, **jupiter8**.
I wanted to get solr suggestions like

**find all the route between *mars1* and *jupiter8***

**find all the route between *mars2* and *jupiter8***

It should also search for a partially typed term. So the following search query also should work.

**find all the route between Mars and Jupi**

Search suggestions:

**find all the route between *mars1* and *jupiter8***

**find all the route between *mars2* and *jupiter8***

In this use case as I needed to tag my search string with relevant entities. i am using ***solrTextTagger***.

My analyzer chain looks like the following

```
    <fieldType name="searchtag" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" postingsFormat="Memory"
    omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="org.opensextant.solrtexttagger.ConcatenateFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="50" minGramSize="2"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

it works for solr 5.3.1. But after solr solr 7.4 ***solrTextTagger*** is added to solr by default. With the added ***solrTextTagger*** i am not able to achive the same result as above.

I have tried this for solr 7.7.1.

```
  <fieldType name="searchtag" class="solr.TextField" postingsFormat="FST50" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" expand="false"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ConcatenateGraphFilterFactory" preserveSep="false" preservePositionIncrements="false"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="50" minGramSize="2"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

The above did not work. I found the reason in the Solr Ref Guide. It states as below

> A tag field, which must be a `TextField`, with `ConcatenateGraphFilterFactory` at the end of the index chain (not the query chain): Set `preservePositionIncrements=false` on that filter. Recommended field settings: `omitNorms=true`, `omitTermFreqAndPositions=true` and `postingsFormat=FST50`.

I tried all the possible arrangements of solr filters. Not able to achieve the same result as I was getting with solr 5.3.1, so I am stuck with solr 5.3.1.

**Is there a way to use solrTextTagger with edge n-gram filter at the bottom of the filter chain?**